# CORS issue on socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am trying to learn socket.io from [this](http://www.tamas.io/simple-chat-application-using-node-js-and-socket-io/) tutorial here. But the problem is I can't make the app run. This is the error I am getting:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LZFI7Tq. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
>   The response had HTTP status code 404.

This is the server side connection

```
var io = require('socket.io');
var socket = io.listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');

// all the people that have joined the chat
var people = {};

socket.on('connection', function (client) {
    console.log('An user connected');
    client.on('join', function(name) {
        people[client.id] = name;

        // client.emit() will only update the client that you are looking
        // at, whereas socket.sockets.emti() will update all connected clients
        client.emit('update', 'You have successfully connected..');
        socket.sockets.emit('update', name + " has joined the conversation..");
        socket.sockets.emit('update-people', people);
    });

    client.on('send', function(msg){
        socket.sockets.emit('chat', people[client.id], msg);
    });

    client.on('disconnect', function() {
        socket.sockets.emit('update', people[client.id] + ' has left the conversation..');
        delete people[client.id];
        socket.sockets.emit('update-people', people);
    });

});
```

And this is the client side connection

```
var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:3000');
```

I have gone through several posts related to this issue but cant solve it. Please help me.

Comment: You need to enable CORS. Add `res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");` in your server code.

Comment: Try `const io = require('socket.io')(3000);` at the server side (remove your second line) and `var socket = io();` on the client side

Comment: @BidhanA, I have updated the question with all my server side code. I don't  understand where do I insert that header.

Comment: @mk12ok after changing the code to what you have suggested the cors issue was gone but i got this `GET http://localhost/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LZFN0DQ 404 (Not Found) universalModuleDefinition:2 `

Comment: You must have some sort of a server running on http://127.0.0.1:3000 for this to work. The tutorial assumes that you already have a server set up(which I think you don't). Check out the "Update!" section to set up your own server.

Comment: But i am running it on apache

Comment: Then enable CORS on Apache..

Comment: As instructed in your first comment?? I dont have any variable named res

Comment: No, that was for a Node.js / Express server. Apache has another way of doing it, I'm sure.

Comment: Okay i'll try and let you know what happened

Comment: The message you get means that  there is no server listening on localhost:3000.. and you say you run it on Apache ?? What do you mean by that? You show us the server code which runs on node.

Comment: @mk12ok, what I meant  is that I am running the app like this, `http://localhost/app_name`. Actually I am still not clear about what `var socket = io.listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');` does. Any clarifications regarding my mistake or wrong understanding would be helpful

Comment: Please show us more code of the server and the client

Comment: Yes you were right. I didn't have any server running on `localhost:3000`. And my previous server side code is already included in my question. But I have fixed it and added node's http module. Its working now. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add this middle-ware on the server where your cookies are created

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept-Type');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    next();
})
```